# How to "un-flatten" array or create an array of pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to group the points of a `<polyline>` into an array of `[x, y]` coordinates. Usually `SVGPolylineElement` items validate with both comma separated values AND space only separated values.

```js
var points = "0 0 50 0 25 50 0 0".split(/\s|,/); // or points="0,0 50,0 25,50 0,0"

// how to group the points like this
points = [[0,0], [50,0], [25,50], [0,0]];
```

I'm working around:

```js
points = [].concat(points.slice().map((v,i) => {
 // what to do here?
 // I know I need to make use of i%2 === 0
 // I don't know how to break the original array
}))
```

I need an ES6 solution to group arrays like shown above.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, if the string contains commas, it will be one solution, if it doesn’t — another solution.

Comment: I tried some `points = [].concat(points.slice().map((v,i) => /* what to do here? */ ))` inside map I need to determine where to break initial array based on `i %2 === 0` but out of ideas.

Comment: For `SVGPolylineElement` both comma and space-only strings are valid.

Comment: Do you originally get the string from an existing element?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky that is irrelevant, since both comma and space-only strings are valid. I'm editing the question to explain.

Comment: Well, this is relevant for me to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = "0 0 50 0 25 50 0 0".split(/\s|,/).map(Number)
const res = []

let curr = 0
while(curr < str.length) {
    res.push([str[curr], str[curr + 1]])
    curr += 2
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: You're returning arrays of strings, not integers.

Comment: Just convert using `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

You could likely achieve the grouping by using `reduce`

```js
// I have omitted parsing these values--I assume that
// it's out of scope for this question
const parsedPoints = [0, 0, 50, 20]

const res = parsedPoints.reduce((coordinates, point, index, array) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return [...coordinates, array.slice(index, index + 2)]
  }

  return coordinates
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

I'm not sure whether you also had difficulties parsing the string into an array of values? I interpreted that the question was about grouping in particular.

Comment: You're returning arrays of strings, not integers.

Comment: This also doesn't check for the other case mentioned in the question:  `'0,0 50,0 25,50 0,0'`.

Comment: I've clarified to answer to more clearly communicate its scope. I interpreted that the issues was with grouping and not parsing the values--in the case where that's not accurate another more complete answer should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If the string contains commas then it’s as simple as:

```js
const pairs = points.split(" ").map((pairRaw) => pairRaw.split(",").map(Number));
```

If not, then it’s a bit harder, — you’ll have to use classic `for` loop:

```js
const pairs = [];
const numbers = points.split(" ").map(Number);

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2)
  pairs.push([ numbers[i], numbers[i + 1] ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const points = '0 0 50 0 25 50 0 0';
const points2 = '0,0 50,0 25,50 0,0';

function coords(points) {

  // Find matches of a set of two numbers
  // separated by a space
  const regex = /(\d+[, ]\d+)/g;

  // Apply the regex to the string to get an
  // array of groups in the style "0 0"
  const match = points.match(regex);

  // Finally map over the array and take
  // each element and split it on the space or
  // the comma and then map over that array
  // to create some integers
  return match.map(el => {
    return el.split(/[ ,]/).map(Number);
  });

}

console.log(coords(points));
console.log(coords(points2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve what you're after:

```js
// Parse the list of strings (extends your code snippet)
let points = "0 0 50 0 25 50 0 0".split(/\s|,/).map(Number);

// Loop and combine
let pointsParsed = []
for (let i=0; i<points.length; i+=2){
  pointsParsed.push([points[i], points[i+1]])
}
```

Assuming that you're splitting with that method as the delimiter you receive between the numbers could be `','` or `' '`

You could condense the LoC down more at the cost of readability on this one